# Python 'NoneType' object is not callable (beginner)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a script using Beautiful Soup that scrapes the start and end dates of the every Wimbledon tennis tournament from 1999-2003 from their respective Wikipedia pages.

I want to get the date range as a list of selectable objects, and I have written a script that achieves this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re 
import os 

year = 1999 
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{tourneyYear}_Wimbledon_Championships"
range = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,]

for number in range:

    response = requests.get(url.format(tourneyYear=year))
    text = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

    overviewTable = soup.find('table', attrs ={'class':"infobox vevent"})

    date = overviewTable.find('th', attrs={"scope":"row"}).parent
    specialResult = date.find('td')
    for sentence in specialResult:
    words = sentence.split()

    print(words)

    year += 1
```

The loop iterates through the webpages ('year' increases by 1 each time and slots into the URL structure that I've defined - this part works perfectly, by the way) and it is supposed to print the list at the end.

For the first two iterations of the loop (for the 1999 and 2000 Wimbledon pages), the list prints just fine. But on the third iteration it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File
 "XYZ", line 21, in <module>
    words = sentence.split()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

The HTML structure of the relevant part of each webpage is identical (as far as I can tell), and the loop only fails for the 2001 iteration (I know this because if I set the loop to iterate for any five-year range that doesn't include 2001, it works just fine).

Is there an error in my code, or does is that particular webpage different in some way that I haven't noticed? I've been racking my brains for days on this one, to no avail!

Comment: It means `specialResult` is empty, `date.find('td')` didn't find anything.

Comment: You have no indent in the `for sentence` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You need to remove the `for`-loop and use [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) in order to obtain the text of each element and then `split()` it:

```
date = overviewTable.find('th', attrs={"scope":"row"}).parent
words = date.find('th').get_text().split()
```

**Explanation:**

[`find()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) does not return a list of strings, it returns a single [`Tag`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag) object. Therefore, what you have in your `specialResult` is a Tag object.

When you iterate over a Tag object, you can get two types of items: strings (for text) and other Tag objects (for inner elements). Your code is failing because `specialResult` does not contain just text, but also a sub-element:

```
[u'25 June \u2013 9 July', <sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-info_1-0"><a href="#cite_note-info-1">[1]</a></sup>]
```

The `sup` element here is not a string, it is a Tag object, it has no `split()` method, and that's why you're getting an exception.